# Chrome bookmarks desktop (embedded in Chrome)

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser, accessibility, usability, icon-packs

I was wondering whether within Chrome it is possible to create a set of bookmarks via web site icons that get placed on a special, scroll-bar and screens enabled, bookmarks page.

That way, WITHIN CHROME, there would be a special page within Chrome, that looked like the Android desktop where all the apps are placed, except that this would be within the web browser.

I think, with this strategy, web site clutter on the desktop, would be avoided.

At the same time, the user would browse the web more... because, besides bookmarks on the bookmarks page, they would have access to their own mini-desktop from within Chrome.

As an application, one could place an icon for each social network website, that the user, used, on this page (even rearranging and moving icons around the Chrome screens).

Of course, the HTML, and the Chrome options menu would need to support placing these bookmarks via special icons on the Chrome desktop bookmark page.

Is this available in Chrome?

If not, then then will this be implemented?

When will this feature be available?

Thanks.